# JavaFX - How to change Background Color for a specific time?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, background-color

I have a Text and an input field. If the input is correct for the text, the background of the input field should change to green. 
Then the program should stop for 1 second (and display the input) Then it should generate a new Text with random() and change the color back to white.

```
input.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            if(value.equals(input.getText())){
                input.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
                System.out.println("right!");

                // now it should wait 1 second
                // and display only the input & green background
                try{ Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException i){
                   throw new Error("interrupted");
                }

                // random changes the Text and the input will reset
                random(); 
                input.setText("");
                input.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        }
      });
```

But the problem is, that the background never changes to green. For this one second it is only displaying my input. Then I get a new Text and my background changes to white.

Have you any ideas how to change the background color for this time?
Thanks for your answers!

**EDIT**

It works with **PauseTransition** instead of Thread so:

```
PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
                wait.setOnFinished(event -> {
                    random();
                    input.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
                    input.setText("");
                });
                wait.play();
```

Comment: The program does "stop for 1 second", which is why you don't see the green text (the program cannot update the UI, since it is "stopped"). You should *never* block the UI thread. Use a `PauseTransition` for functionality like this.

Comment: See if you can figure it out using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task) code. If you can't, come back with an altered question.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370618/2189127), which is perhaps a little simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Edited my question