# JavaFX. Threads in button click

Tags: multithreading, button, javafx, imageview

After click myButton runs 2 Thread. First change the button image, second - loop. I want my program at first сhange image and after run loop. But it doesnt work, they are finished in one moment.

```
myButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                        imageView.setFitHeight(my_button_height - 16);
                        imageView.setFitWidth(my_button_width - 16);
                        myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff00; ");
                        myButton.setGraphic(imageView);
                    }
                });
                thread.run();
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                            System.out.println(i);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread1.run();
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried to add .join. It didnt help

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  If it is animation, then use [JavaFX animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm).  If it is not, then please explain it.  Why do you create a thread to show an image? (that isn't needed) Why do you loop 15 times sleeping? (that doesn't accomplish anything)

Comment: I want my button to change the image and then start  the loop. It is not animation. Click - boom - we can see image in the button - boom - start loop.
What about thread. I thought my program worked so fast, that I couldnt see how the image changed.I wanted to put thread to sleep and checked . But it didnt worked.

Comment: But what is the purpose of the loop?  Why is there a thread for it?  What does it do in your actual application?  I don't know why you are using threads at all, so it is very difficult to advise on how you should use them correctly to accomplish an unknown goal.  But at least one thing you should never do, is to join the UI thread to another thread.  And another thing you should never do is run a thread.  Threads should be started, not run.

Comment: If you really need concurrency, then study [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) to learn how to use concurrency in JavaFX applications.  There are numerous examples in the [`Task` javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: ok. I explain what I want. I develop the game, where to find identical cards with image. Card is button with image. When player opened two cards, my program check them and if they are identical everything is good, in another way closed. But I ran into a problem when player open second card, he cannot see it and both cards close
I thought threads help me, but no.

Comment: Probably you want a [`PauseTransition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369591/updating-your-ui-and-forcibly-waiting-before-continuing-javafx/35370618#35370618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a `PauseTransition`, not threads**

You don't need to use threads to implement your requirement.

> the game, where to find identical cards with image. Card is button with image. When player opened two cards, my program check them and if they are identical everything is good, in another way closed. But I ran into a problem when player open second card, he cannot see it

The issue is that there is no pause after a player action under certain conditions, so the player cannot see the cards they have flipped over, before they are flipped back.

This can be fixed using a `PauseTransition`.  Usage is explained in this answer:

- [Updating your UI and forcibly waiting before continuing JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369591/updating-your-ui-and-forcibly-waiting-before-continuing-javafx/35370618#35370618)

**Example**

Here is some example code for a memory game.  The example:

- Applies a pause transition after the user has flipped two cards.
- UI input is disabled during the pause.
- When the pause is complete, the UI is updated (either flipping the cards back if they did not match or removing them from the board if they did match).

The relevant code is the snippet:

```
public MemoryGame(String tileText) {
    ObservableList<Tile> tiles = createTiles(tileText);
    FilteredList<Tile> visibleTiles = tiles.filtered(Tile::isShowing);

    board = createBoard(tiles);

    PauseTransition pauseForCompletion = new PauseTransition(
            FLIP_PAUSE_DURATION
    );
    pauseForCompletion.setOnFinished(e ->
            completeMove(tiles, visibleTiles, board)
    );

    visibleTiles.addListener((ListChangeListener<Tile>) c -> {
        if (visibleTiles.size() == 2) {
            board.setDisable(true);
            pauseForCompletion.playFromStart();
        }
    });
}
```

This is just a demo app, it isn't thoroughly tested and may have some bugs in it.  The demo is probably more complex then needed, it uses a filtered list to register flipped cards, but could be simplified with just a couple of object properties to represent flipped cards instead.

For a slightly more complex app (or even this one refactored), I'd suggest using a more MVC style approach where the game state is modeled and tested independent of the UI, but for this proof-of-concept demo, the code below is OK for that purpose.

Hopefully, it illustrates one way to use the `PauseTransition` concept to solve an issue similar to the one you have.

*MemoryGame.java*

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Labeled;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MemoryGame {
    private static final Duration FLIP_PAUSE_DURATION = Duration.seconds(
            1
    );

    private final TilePane board;
    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper solved = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(
            false
    );

    public MemoryGame(String tileText) {
        ObservableList<Tile> tiles = createTiles(tileText);
        FilteredList<Tile> visibleTiles = tiles.filtered(Tile::isShowing);

        board = createBoard(tiles);

        PauseTransition pauseForCompletion = new PauseTransition(
                FLIP_PAUSE_DURATION
        );
        pauseForCompletion.setOnFinished(e ->
                completeMove(tiles, visibleTiles, board)
        );

        visibleTiles.addListener((ListChangeListener<Tile>) c ->
                respondToMove(visibleTiles, board, pauseForCompletion)
        );
    }

    private static void respondToMove(
            FilteredList<Tile> visibleTiles,
            TilePane board,
            PauseTransition pauseForCompletion
    ) {
        if (visibleTiles.size() == 2) {
            board.setDisable(true);
            pauseForCompletion.playFromStart();
        }
    }

    private void completeMove(
            ObservableList<Tile> tiles,
            FilteredList<Tile> visibleTiles,
            TilePane board
    ) {
        long nShowing = visibleTiles.stream()
                .map(Labeled::getText)
                .distinct()
                .count();

        if (nShowing == 1) { // all visible tiles match
            // replace all matching tiles with a blank pane.
            for (Tile tile : visibleTiles) {
                int tileIdx = board.getChildren().indexOf(tile);
                board.getChildren().set(tileIdx, new Pane());
            }
            for (int i = visibleTiles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tiles.remove(visibleTiles.get(i));
            }

            if (tiles.isEmpty()) {
                solved.set(true);
            }
        } else {
            // tiles don't match, so hide them until they are turned again.
            for (int i = visibleTiles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                visibleTiles.get(i).setShowing(false);
            }
        }

        board.setDisable(false);
    }

    private static TilePane createBoard(ObservableList<Tile> tiles) {
        TilePane board = new TilePane(
                10, 10
        );

        board.getStyleClass().add("board");

        board.getChildren().addAll(tiles);
        board.setPrefColumns((int) Math.sqrt(tiles.size()));
        board.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        return board;
    }

    private static ObservableList<Tile> createTiles(String tileText) {
        List<String> gameText =
                (tileText + tileText)
                        .chars()
                        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        Collections.shuffle(gameText);

        ObservableList<Tile> tiles = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                tile -> new Observable[] { tile.showingProperty() }
        );
        gameText.stream()
                .map(Tile::new)
                .forEachOrdered(tiles::add);
        return tiles;
    }

    public TilePane getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public boolean isSolved() {
        return solved.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty solvedProperty() {
        return solved.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}
```

*Tile.java*

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

class Tile extends Button {
    private static final String BLANK = " ";

    private final BooleanProperty showing = new SimpleBooleanProperty(
            false
    );

    public Tile(String tileText) {
        getStyleClass().add("tile");

        textProperty().bind(
                Bindings
                        .when(showing)
                        .then(tileText)
                        .otherwise(BLANK)
        );

        setOnAction(e -> setShowing(true));
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return showing.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty showingProperty() {
        return showing;
    }

    public void setShowing(boolean showing) {
        this.showing.set(showing);
    }
}
```

*MemoryGameApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MemoryGameApp extends Application {
    private static final String TILE_TEXT = "Qn39Pzr#";
    private static final String CSS =
            """
            data:text/css,
            .board .button:disabled {
                -fx-opacity: 1;
            }
            .tile {
                -fx-font-family: monospace; -fx-font-size: 40px;
            }
            """;

    private MemoryGame memoryGame;
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        memoryGame = new MemoryGame(TILE_TEXT);

        scene = new Scene(memoryGame.getBoard());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        memoryGame.solvedProperty().addListener(new EndGameListener());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class EndGameListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (memoryGame.isSolved()) {
                memoryGame.solvedProperty().removeListener(this);
                memoryGame = new MemoryGame(TILE_TEXT);
                memoryGame.solvedProperty().addListener(this);
                scene.setRoot(memoryGame.getBoard());
            }
        }
    }
}
```